# How to script External collaboration settings in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Would like to be able to control two settings in Azure Active Directory user settings:

- External collaboration settings > “Members can invite”
- External collaboration settings > “Guests can invite”

As we already know, you can control just about everything in Azure with powershell, except these two things.

The internet, azure docs, and other resources, known to me, have been utilized to no real results.

Code: this is what we are looking to start.

Would like to say "Get-AzAADExternalCollaborationsSettings" then use the results to say "Set-AzAADExternalCollaborationsSettings".

[AzAADUserSettings Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyrS2.png)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no built-in powershell command for the external collaboration settings, the two settings call the azure undisclosed api `https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/xxxx`, the workaround I can just find is to invoke the api with powershell, here is a sample for you to refer, it calls a different api, but the logic should be similar. You can catch the requests of the two settings via fiddler and follow the sample to have a try.

Sample:http://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/2018/04/how-to-grant-oauth2-permissions-to-an-azure-ad-application-using-powershell-unattended-silently/

```
Function Grant-OAuth2PermissionsToApp{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Username, #global administrator username
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Password, #global administrator password
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$azureAppId #application ID of the azure application you wish to admin-consent to
    )

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $secpasswd)
    $res = login-azurermaccount -Credential $mycreds
    $context = Get-AzureRmContext
    $tenantId = $context.Tenant.Id
    $refreshToken = @($context.TokenCache.ReadItems() | Where-Object {$_.tenantId -eq $tenantId -and $_.ExpiresOn -gt (Get-Date)})[0].RefreshToken
    $body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"
    $apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod "https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    $header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiToken.access_token
    'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
    'x-ms-client-request-id'= [guid]::NewGuid()
    'x-ms-correlation-id' = [guid]::NewGuid()}
    $url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/$azureAppId/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=true"
    Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $url –Headers $header –Method POST -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through monitoring the webbrowser network reuest i was able to get the correct API URL `https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Directories/B2BDirectoryProperties`

This should be a Powershell command. Hopfully Microsoft does't break this API.

Here are some snippets of what i am using:

```bsh
# Get API Token
$mycreds = Get-Credential
if($tenantId){
  $res = login-azurermaccount -Credential $mycreds -TenantId $tenantId.ToLower()
}else{
  $res = login-azurermaccount -Credential $mycreds
}
$context = Get-AzureRmContext
$tenantId = $context.Tenant.Id
$refreshToken = $context.TokenCache.ReadItems().RefreshToken
$body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"
$apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod "https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'


# Get current settings
$header = @{
  'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
  "Origin"="https://portal.azure.com"
  'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiToken.access_token
  'x-ms-client-request-id'= [guid]::NewGuid()
}
$url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Directories/B2BDirectoryProperties"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop


# Change settings
$settings = @{
  allowInvitations = $true
  limitedAccessCanAddExternalUsers = $false
  restrictDirectoryAccess = $true
  usersCanAddExternalUsers = $false
}
$body = $settings | ConvertTo-Json
$header = @{
  'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
  "Origin"="https://portal.azure.com"
  'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiToken.access_token
  'x-ms-client-request-id'= [guid]::NewGuid()
}
$url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Directories/B2BDirectoryProperties"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method "PUT" -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

Thnx for pointing me in the right direction Joy.