# Read list of Target domains from Azure External Identities collaboration settings using c#

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I need to extract the full list of Target domains (found under Azure Active Directory \ External Identities \ External collaboration settings \ Target domains).
Is this possible using Microsoft Graph, and if so what endpoint should I use, and what graph permissions would I need to add?
If not Graph, how else could I access this info? I'm using c# to extract the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no Graph endpoint for your requirement.

However, there are other two  alternative options :

**Option 1 :**

Using Powershell

[Get-AzureADPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)

Sample :

```
$currentpolicy = Get-AzureADPolicy | ?{$_.Type -eq 'B2BManagementPolicy'} | select -First 1
```

You can invoke these scripts from your C# application.

**Option 2:**

Using the below endpoint :

```
https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Directories/B2BDirectoryProperties
```

However, this is not documented. This may or may not work in a longer run.

**Reference to a similar thread :**
[How to script External collaboration settings in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625413/how-to-script-external-collaboration-settings-in-azure)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, with MS Graph for B2B, we can create [invites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but we do have some options regarding this by using  [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/allow-deny-list)